# Как заполнить массив в python3

Tags: python-3.x, массивы

Даны числа n и m. Нужно реализовать заполнение двух массивов n на m в определенном порядке.

1)

```
7 8 9

4 5 6

1 2 3
```

2)

```
3 6 9

2 5 8

1 4 7
```

Нужно чтобы алгоритм работал для любых n, m.

Например:
1) для m = 4 и n = 2

```
5 6 7 8 

1 2 3 4
```

Comment: А вы сами, как пробовали решить эту задачу? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: Да, я пробывал решить сам. Это только часть задачи на которой я и застрял. Пункт 1 я выполнил сам, но не думаю что этот способ наилучший, как решать пункт 2, я даже не представляю

Comment: Попробуй сделать два цикла. Попробуй сначала решить задачу только для одной переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение для пункта 1.

```
from itertools import count

x = count(n*m, -1)

firstLanding = [[next(x) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей задачи лучше всего использовать модуль numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
transp_arr = arr.transpose()
print(arr)
print(transp_arr)
```

Вывод

**arr**
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
**transp_arr**
[[ 0  4  8]
 [ 1  5  9]
 [ 2  6 10]
 [ 3  7 11]]

```
arange(12) #нужен для заполнения «массива» и выводится в таком виде [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.... до 11]
reshape(3, 4) #как видно из названия происходит переформирование, в нашем случае 3 на 4, но самое главное чтоб количество столбцов и строк соответствовало количеству элементов
```